# Custom control rendering weird in Tapcontrol

Tags: c#, rendering, custom-controls

Here is an odd one and it will be a bit long to describe so bear with me on this one.

I have a control made for c# 4 client profile called `Toggleswitch` (tsw). This toggleswitch is design to act like the metro switch, and that is does splendidly ... until it is added to a Tap control/Tap page then :

- the rendering acts all weird not drawing the background properly and the on/off label don’t show up. This affects other controls as well, it like the Whole form won't draw.
- also both VS 2010 and 2013 design editors properties fields freeze up so I can't access the other controls
- and if left in normal the program won't build ... basically crashed VS..

BUT, if I change the tap control from normal to either flatbutton or button then it stops and runs smoothly as always and that is fine, but then I started wondering why it don't render in the normal

So here is what I have tried

- the tsw extends `Buttonbase` for clickability. So I changed that to control then the `OnPaint` gets called in a unlimited loop so that don’t help, also the click don’t Work but that is less important right now
- I extended of button, no help there still weird
- override every single method from both button and buttonbase to see if that helped still nothing.
- After looking at the forms designer I found that the only property the gets changed is the `UseVisualStyleBackColor` when false it works when true it don't, so I made an override that forces it to be false, still doesn't work :/
- I even tried to remove the partial keyword.
- I spend half a day reading about the defriend methods of both tap and button controls
- even found a custom control test the extended of button that worked fine, but there was no reason for it because the only different from what I could see was an if statement in the `OnPaint` about some rendering.

.... Nothing works ....

Here is the togglewitch in its entirety:

```
public partial class ToggleSwith : ButtonBase
{
        object _Lock = new object();
        private Color _OffColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
        private Color _OnColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        private bool _ColorText = false;
        // private bool _BeenDrawn = false;
        private bool _Checked = false;

        [Browsable(false)]
        public override string Text { get { return null; } }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public override bool AutoSize{get{return false;}}
        [Browsable(false)]
        public override ContentAlignment TextAlign { get { return ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft; } }
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public virtual Color OffColor { get { return _OffColor; } set { _OffColor = value; Invalidate(); } }
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public virtual Color OnColor { get { return _OnColor; } set { _OnColor = value; Invalidate(); } }
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public virtual bool ColorText { get { return _ColorText; } set { _ColorText = value; Invalidate(); } }
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public virtual bool Checked { get { return _Checked; } set { _Checked = value; Invalidate(); } }
        new public bool UseVisualStyleBackColor { get { return false; } set{} }

        protected override Size DefaultSize { get { return new Size(80, 18); } }
        protected override Size DefaultMinimumSize { get { return new Size(40, 13); } }

        public event EventHandler ToggleChanged;

        public ToggleSwith()
        {
            this.Size = new Size(80, 18);
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Click += ToggleSwith_Click;
        }

        void ToggleSwith_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lock (_Lock)
            {
                if (_Checked) _Checked = false;
                else _Checked = true;
            }
            OnToggleChanged();            
        }

        private void OnToggleChanged()
        {
            if (ToggleChanged != null)
            {
                EventArgs ea = new EventArgs();
                ToggleChanged(this, ea);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.Clear();
            int toggleblocsize=(int)this.Size.Width/8;
            int indent = 23;
            int labelx = 2;
            // Declare and instantiate a new pen.
            SolidBrush OffPen = new SolidBrush(this.OffColor);
            SolidBrush OnPen = new SolidBrush(this.OnColor);
            SolidBrush BackgroundPen = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
            SolidBrush BlackPen = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlText);
            Pen ControlDarkPen = new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark);
            Pen ControlPen = new Pen(SystemColors.Control);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackgroundPen,0, 0, this.Size.Width,this.Size.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(ControlDarkPen, indent, -0, this.Size.Width - (indent+1), this.Size.Height-1);
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Font = this.Font;
            l.Size = new Size((indent-labelx),this.Size.Height);

            // if(this.Size.Height <13)l.Location= new Point(labelx,-1);
            //  else l.Location = new Point(labelx, 0);

            l.TextAlign = TextAlign;
            l.ForeColor = this.ForeColor;

            if (this._Checked)
            {
                //ligth
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(OnPen, (indent + 2), 2, this.Size.Width - (indent + 4), this.Size.Height - 4);
                //Toggle
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(ControlPen, this.Size.Width - (toggleblocsize+1), -0, this.Size.Width - (indent + 1), this.Size.Height - 1);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BlackPen, this.Size.Width - (toggleblocsize), -1, this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height + 1);
                if (ColorText) l.ForeColor = OnColor;
                l.Text = "On";
            }
            else
            {
                //ligth
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(OffPen, (indent + 2), 2, this.Size.Width - (indent + 4), this.Size.Height - 4);
                //Toggle
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(ControlPen, indent , -0, (toggleblocsize + 1), this.Size.Height - 1);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BlackPen, (indent+1) , -1,(toggleblocsize), this.Size.Height + 1);
                if (ColorText) l.ForeColor = this.ForeColor;
                l.Text = "Off";
            }
            this.Controls.Add(l);
        }

        public override Size GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
        {
            return new Size(80, 18);
        }
    }
```

It is not that I can't live with a flat tapcontrol it is just the why it doesn't work that bugs me ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Lastly some visual documentation of the problems:

Here is how it should work:

[image: here is how it should Work]

This is with a tap on normal

[image: this is with a tap on normal.]

Comment: Thanks mark that cleaned it up nicely :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed so that it now work, turns out that there was a few things wrong.

First of the base class was  wrong, it should be a control

```
   public class ToggleSwith : Control
```

and the on paint event changed to this

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Controls.Clear();
        int toggleblocsize = (int)this.Size.Width / 6;
        int indent = 23;
        int labelx = 2;
        // Declare and instantiate a new pen.
        SolidBrush OffPen = new SolidBrush(this.OffColor);
        SolidBrush OnPen = new SolidBrush(this.OnColor);
        Rectangle texttangle = new Rectangle(new Point(labelx, 0), new Size(indent - labelx, this.Size.Height));


        SolidBrush BackgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(this.Parent.BackColor);
        SolidBrush ToggleBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlText);
        SolidBrush TextBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlText);
        Pen ControlDarkPen = new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark);
        Pen ControlPen = new Pen(SystemColors.Control);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackgroundBrush, 0, 0, this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), indent, 0, this.Size.Width - indent, this.Size.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(ControlDarkPen, indent, -0, this.Size.Width - (indent + 1), this.Size.Height - 1);
        if (!this.Enabled)
        {
            OffPen = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Control);
            OnPen = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Control);
            ToggleBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlDark);
            TextBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Control);
        }
        if (this._Checked)
        {
            //ligth
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(OnPen, (indent + 2), 2, this.Size.Width - (indent + 4), this.Size.Height - 4);
            //Toggle
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(ControlPen, this.Size.Width - (toggleblocsize + 1), -0, this.Size.Width - (indent + 1), this.Size.Height - 1);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ToggleBrush, this.Size.Width - (toggleblocsize), -1, this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height + 1);
            if (ColorText && this.Enabled) TextBrush = new SolidBrush(OnColor);//_label.ForeColor = OnColor;
            // _label.Text = "On";
            // Draw string to screen.
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, OnText, this.Font, texttangle, TextBrush.Color, this.Parent.BackColor,
                                TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter |
                                TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter |
                                TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
        }
        else
        {
            //ligth
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(OffPen, (indent + 2), 2, this.Size.Width - (indent + 4), this.Size.Height - 4);
            //Toggle
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(ControlPen, indent, -0, (toggleblocsize + 1), this.Size.Height - 1);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ToggleBrush, (indent + 1), -1, (toggleblocsize), this.Size.Height + 1);
            if (ColorText && this.Enabled) TextBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlText);
            // Draw string to screen.
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, OffText, this.Font, texttangle, TextBrush.Color, this.Parent.BackColor,
                            TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter |
                            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter |
                            TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
        }
```

that got the graphics result i was looking for.